# Nexus OSS not starting after adding the R repository plug-in

Tags: nexus, nexus3

Nexus OSS 3.7.1-02 running on RHEL 7. I am referring to the '[permanent install](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-r#most-permanent-install)' section of the R plug-in.

I added the entries in the `nexus-oss-feature-3.7.1-02-features.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0" name="nexus-oss-feature">
    <feature name="nexus-oss-feature" description="com.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-oss-feature" version="3.7.1.02">
        <details>com.sonatype.nexus.assemblies:nexus-oss-feature</details>
        <feature prerequisite="true" dependency="false">nexus-core-feature</feature>
.
.
.
<!--Start: Added for R plug-in-->
        <feature version="3.7.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-rubygems</feature>
        <feature version="1.0.1" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-r</feature>
        <feature version="3.7.1.02" prerequisite="false" dependency="false">nexus-repository-yum</feature>
        <!--End: Added for R plug-in-->
        <bundle>mvn:com.sonatype.nexus/nexus-licensing-extension/3.7.1-02</bundle>
.
.
.
    <feature name="nexus-rutauth-plugin" description="com.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-rutauth-plugin" version="3.7.1.02">
        <details>com.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-rutauth-plugin</details>
        <bundle>mvn:com.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-rutauth-plugin/3.7.1-02</bundle>
    </feature>
    <!--Start: Added for R plug-in-->
    <feature name="nexus-repository-r" description="org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-r" version="1.0.1">
        <details>org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-r</details>
        <bundle>mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-r/1.0.1</bundle>
    </feature>
    <!--End: Added for R plug-in-->
</features>
```

When I restart Nexus, I get errors in `nexus.log`. On a quick search in the Maven public repository, I didn't find any artifacts or anything at all pertaining to `mvn:org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-repository-r/1.0.1`. Shouldn't that tag have something that makes it pickup the artifact `<nexus_dir>/system/org/sonatype/nexus/plugins/nexus-repository-r/1.0.1/nexus-repository-r-1.0.1.jar`?

```
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature; type=karaf.feature; version="[3.7.1.02,3.7.1.02]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=3.7.1.02)(version<=3.7.1.02))" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02: missing requirement [nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-repository-r; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api)(version>=3.8.0))"]]]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolutionError.toException(ResolutionError.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:389)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:375)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:347)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:216)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:263)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1176)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl$1.call(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-03-13 10:45:19,633+0000 ERROR [jetty-main-1]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.BootstrapListener - Failed to initialize
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature; type=karaf.feature; version="[3.7.1.02,3.7.1.02]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=3.7.1.02)(version<=3.7.1.02))" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02: missing requirement [nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-repository-r; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api)(version>=3.8.0))"]]]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.contextInitialized(NexusContextListener.java:176)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.ListenerTracker.addingService(ListenerTracker.java:47)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.ListenerTracker.addingService(ListenerTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:870)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:318)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.BootstrapListener.contextInitialized(BootstrapListener.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:274)
Caused by: org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature; type=karaf.feature; version="[3.7.1.02,3.7.1.02]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=3.7.1.02)(version<=3.7.1.02))" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02: missing requirement [nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-repository-r; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api)(version>=3.8.0))"]]]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolutionError.toException(ResolutionError.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:389)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:375)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:347)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:216)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:263)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1176)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl$1.call(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-03-13 10:45:19,633+0000 WARN  [jetty-main-1]  *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1a1e279e{/,file:///usr/lib/nexus-3.7.1-02/public/,UNAVAILABLE}
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature; type=karaf.feature; version="[3.7.1.02,3.7.1.02]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=3.7.1.02)(version<=3.7.1.02))" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02: missing requirement [nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-repository-r; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api)(version>=3.8.0))"]]]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.contextInitialized(NexusContextListener.java:176)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.ListenerTracker.addingService(ListenerTracker.java:47)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.ListenerTracker.addingService(ListenerTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:870)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:318)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.BootstrapListener.contextInitialized(BootstrapListener.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:274)
Caused by: org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature; type=karaf.feature; version="[3.7.1.02,3.7.1.02]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=3.7.1.02)(version<=3.7.1.02))" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02: missing requirement [nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-repository-r; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api)(version>=3.8.0))"]]]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolutionError.toException(ResolutionError.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:389)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:375)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:347)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:216)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:263)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1176)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl$1.call(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-03-13 10:45:19,643+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@718a49cb{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}
2018-03-13 10:45:19,643+0000 ERROR [jetty-main-1]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Failed to start
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature; type=karaf.feature; version="[3.7.1.02,3.7.1.02]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=3.7.1.02)(version<=3.7.1.02))" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02: missing requirement [nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-repository-r; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api)(version>=3.8.0))"]]]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.contextInitialized(NexusContextListener.java:176)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.ListenerTracker.addingService(ListenerTracker.java:47)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.ListenerTracker.addingService(ListenerTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:870)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:318)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.BootstrapListener.contextInitialized(BootstrapListener.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:274)
Caused by: org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature; type=karaf.feature; version="[3.7.1.02,3.7.1.02]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=nexus-oss-feature)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=3.7.1.02)(version<=3.7.1.02))" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02: missing requirement [nexus-oss-feature/3.7.1.02] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=nexus-repository-r; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]" [caused by: Unable to resolve nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1: missing requirement [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-r/1.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api)(version>=3.8.0))"]]]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolutionError.toException(ResolutionError.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:389)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:375)
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:347)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:216)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:263)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1176)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl$1.call(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-03-13 10:45:19,931+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener - Uptime: 7 seconds and 286 milliseconds
2018-03-13 10:45:19,934+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager - Stop KERNEL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin `nexus-repository-r` since version `1.0.1` requires Nexus Repository Manager `3.8.0-02` or above. So, either upgrade your Nexus Repository Manager (recommended) or downgrade your plugin.

Here's abstract from the plugin's documentation:

> Of note, version 1.0.1 is for Nexus Repository 3.8.0-02 and above,
>   please use 1.0.0 if you are using an older version.